# Animation using a blend tree, 2D Simple Directional not using the correct animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

Why does this deer not switch to its 'Deer Move-Left' animation until the value is at 1. From my understanding, I would think it would switch over right when the value goes from 0 to -0.01.

[image]

Comment: Could you show the according animation clips? I actually tried to set it up and it works for me as expected switching the sprites when crossing `0`